# Android Studio Facebook SDK autoimport

Tags: android, facebook, maven

I'm trying to include the Facebook SDK to my AS Project.
I use the Maven Repo for it.
In build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
}
```

Now, when I want to start init the facebook sdk in my mainactivity:

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
}
```

I get "cannot resolve symbol FacebookSdk."
Normally, I would autoimport `com.facebook.FacebookSdk;` with alt+enter, but AS told me "cannot find declaration to go to".
When I try to import it manually, I only can import com.facebook.*;
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); works now, but I want the autoimport/autocomplete function. I have this problem only with the facebook sdk.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to build the project?

Comment: Solved it on my own. It was a problem with AS, not with facebook. I reinstalled AS and now it works fine.